# metadata from Apache FOP generated PDF shows vulnerable software

Tags: pdf, imagemagick-convert, apache-fop

i'm using Apache fop 2.7 to generate a PDF with that contains text and images, which is later signed with CAdES signature. /exiftool shows:

```
---- ICC-header ----
Profile CMM Type                : Little CMS
Profile Version                 : 2.3.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2004:08:13 12:18:06
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : Little CMS
Device Model                    :
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Little CMS
```

I traced back to this tag in the PDF: [/ICCBased 2 0 R], if i have this tag removed from the PDF, exitfool no longer shows the metadata, but when i attach the CAdES signature, the metadata pop ups again. I think is it related to the images i use, hence i removed the metadata in the images by using ' magick.exe   convert  -strip image.png newImage.png', to no avail. How can i have this metadata removed without manual postprocess?

By vulnerability i meant that exiftool reported software affected by some CVE, i found this PDF online.

https://sec.report/nsm/Charm-Finance-P-L-C/Portal/NI-000006423

Our FOP installation is a 2.7 Apache FOP jar along with its dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-util:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-events:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-shared-resources:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.14:compile
```

The signing process is web based, so i cannot comment on it. I also tried t remove the ICC in all pages with Apache PDFBox like this:

```
for (COSName name : page.getResources().getColorSpaceNames())
                {
                    PDColorSpace cs = page.getResources().getColorSpace(name);
                    if (cs instanceof PDICCBased)
                    {
                        page.getResources().getCOSObject().removeItem(name);
                      
                        
                    }
                }
```

And save the page to a new doc

Comment: **A** What do you mean by *vulnerable software*? **B** Please share an example file.

Comment: Ah. Well, the software shown has been used in the **generation** of some part of your pdf, it is not by itself in the pdf, so there is no reason to worry about the PDF itself. That being said, the information is from an ICC color profile, so it might have been added e.g. from FOP own resources, not via an image. Thus, you may want to look into your FOP installation.

Comment: Also you say that by signing the lcms reference returns. You might want to share details on your signing process, it may well be that your signing software also adds a color profile.

Comment: thanks, i update the answer

Comment: *"I also tried t remove the ICC in all pages with Apache PDFBox like this"* - This can damage the PDF considerably. *"The signing process is web based, so i cannot comment on it."* - please share a file before and after signing for analysis.